# Golang chromedp localhost, how to extract text from element

Tags: golang, chromedp

Если в приведенном ниже коде изменить строку localhost `http://[::1]:8080/user` на реальный сайт, то он сработает правильно и выдаст указанное `.myclass` текстовое содержимое с сайта.

```
package main

import (
"context"
"log"
"strings"

"github.com/chromedp/chromedp"
)

func main() {
    // create context
    ctx, cancel := chromedp.NewContext(context.Background())
    defer cancel()

    // run task list
    var res string
    err := chromedp.Run(ctx,
        chromedp.Navigate(`http://[::1]:8080/user`),
        chromedp.Text(`.myclass`, &res, chromedp.NodeVisible),
    ) 
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    log.Println(strings.TrimSpace(res))
}
```

html `сайта` и `локалхоста` идентичны, но в случае последнего выдаёт ошибку: `page load error net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED exit status 1`. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как работать с localhost, чтобы также получить с него содержимое?

Comment: `http://[::1]:8080/user` замените на `http://localhost:8080/user`

Comment: При такой замене, - задумывается навсегда, - и выхожу по `Ctr+C`. Возможно, сам подход у меня не верный: на уже существующей вкладке хрома по указанному локалхосту загружен простой html, с которого хочу получить данные, а прога вероятно заточена `открывать вкладку` по адресу .. не пойму, подскажите, плиз.

Comment: @Senior Pomidor, да Вы правы, сработало именно с `http://localhost:8080/user`. Моя проблема в том, что я рассчитывал получать и те данные, которые вносил в контекст html *вручную* через F12 в консоли скриптом или правкой html в закладке Elements. Полагал, что если вижу результат таких изменений на экране после правки контекста, - то и прогой могу их получать. Но нет, не пойму почему, возможно, прога берёт из новой вкладки, где таких изменений нет. Спасибо.

Comment: chromedp сам открывает новую вкладку и переходит по ссылке. поэтому ваши изменения не влияют на него